# switch does not do what I want it to do

Tags: c

### My Task is a simple Boolean Calculator

I want to make a simple boolean calculator, which uses OR, AND, NAND and XOR. This is what it has to do:

If the user enters a string starting with `q` (like `quit`) at any time, the program should immediately exit. If the user enters a string starting with `c` (like `cancel`) at any time, the program should abort the current calculation and ask for the first argument again. If the user enters anything other than a `0`, a `1`, or a string starting with `c` or `q`, you should display an error (see below) and ask for the same value again.

Now, I know this is probably very silly, but I really have started right now programming...

It doesn't matter what I enter, it only retuns the "You chose to quit!" 
Why does it "ignore" the switch?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // Declaration Part
    char user_input[100];

    //Main Body
    gets(user_input);
    while (user_input[0] == !'q') {
        switch (user_input[0]) {
          case '0':
          case '1':
            printf("You chose boolean algebra! \n");
            break;
          case 'c':
            printf("%s\n", "You chose to continue!");
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("You chose to quit! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (user_input[0] == !'q')` ==> `while (user_input[0] != 'q')`

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (eg  `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), improve your code till you get no warnings, then **use the debugger** (`gdb`), e.g. to run the program step by step.

Comment: BTW `gets` is obsolete and dangerous. Use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Please read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of *every* function that you are using.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 major problems in your code:

- The condition `while (user_input[0] == !'q')` should be written `while (user_input[0] != 'q')`
- The obsolete function `gets()` should never be used.  Use `fgets()` instead.
- You do not read a new line in the `while` loop... the condition is constant, you have either an infinite loop (if you type enter directly) or one you never enter.

Here is a better version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    // Declaration Part
    char input[100];

    //Main Body
    while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL && input[0] != 'q') {
        switch (input[0]) {
          case '0':
          case '1':
            printf("You chose boolean algebra! \n");
            break;
          case 'c':
            printf("%s\n", "You chose to continue!");
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("You chose to quit!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator `!` is Boolean, if the operand is non-zero, the result is `false` which implicitly casts to zero in your condition expression:

```
user_input[0] == !'q'
```

You are simply comparing `user_input[0]` to zero so the switch is never entered.  That is to say it is not switch that is not doing what you want - it is the incorrect Boolean expression in the `if(...)` that precedes it.

What you need is the *binary operator* `!=`

```
user_input[0] != 'q'
```

Comment: Note as stated in other answers this code has other issues - but they were not part of your question, so I have deliberately not addresses those.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it "ignore" the switch?

It is not *executing* the switch because it is inside a conditional block for which the condition is *never* true.  You are addressing the wrong part of the code; why it does not execute the switch should be obvious, the question you should then ask is rather "*Why is the `while` condition never true?*".

The operator `!` is boolean, if the operand is non-zero, the result is `false` which implicitly casts to zero when compared to an integer.  In your condition expression:

```
user_input[0] == !'q'
```

you are simply comparing `user_input[0]` to zero so the loop body and therefore the switch is never entered.  So it is not switch that is not doing what you want - it is the incorrect boolean expression in the `while(...)` that precedes it.

What you need is the *binary operator* `!=`

```
user_input[0] != 'q'
```